# Jumping higher when the player touches a trigger collider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, platformer, rigid-body-dynamics, jumping

Im using Unity engine to create a 2D platformer. My character can single/double jump, this works fine everywhere except when i am in range of a collider with a IsTrigger set to TRUE, then my character can triple jump if jump is pressed repeatedly. This can used as an exploit in my game when collecting pickups :( How can i stop this from happening? Please assist

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // This is the Jump code
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
        anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);
        anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if (grounded)
        {
            doubleJump = false;
        }

void Update()
    { //This is pressed to get the player to jump
        if((grounded || !doubleJump) && (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || didPlayerJump || wasEnemyStomped == true))
        {
            JumpAction(); // rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForce)) triggered in this function
            if(!grounded && !doubleJump)
            {
                doubleJump = true;
            }
```

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: I am actually experiencing a similar phenomenon, when using add force with a `isGrounded` bool.  Will see if I can't work something out and post and update

Comment: Im new to the forum, apologies for the messy code above. I have been pulling what little hair i have left out on this issue ive done so many experiments and still the solution eludes me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'd recommend reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and editing your original post to include the code you put in your comment.

Comment: Did you want to jump higher in one jump or have the ability to double jump?

Comment: @McAden Thank you for the advice and the warm welcome :) Please see the snippets of code above

Comment: @lase Thanks for the reply. I have setup a double jump already, my problem is my character can triple jump if jump is pressed repeatedly, once the player is standing inside of a Trigger. I need to prevent the player from being able to triple jump when collecting things, as it can be used as an exploit in the game.

Comment: Is the trigger for the item collection resetting grounded? Alternatively, is the item collection instance on the same layer as the ground? (as that also seems to reset 'grounded')

Comment: Hi @McAden Thank you very much :) That was exactly it. I just had to put all of the collectibles on the same layer as my playable character so that the collectibles don't reset my IsGround bool on touch. After more than a week of struggling and at least 30+ hours of experimenting and research i have fixed the issue. Thanks again, is there a way to Up Vote your solution???

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem for a while. I was able to actually jump forever when I attacked. It turns out the problem was with the "whatIsGround" layer. Make sure everything is layered and the things you don't want to restart the jumpprocess are not checked in that mask layer. It solved my problem and might solve yours.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are quite trying to do when the `collider with a IsTrigger` is true.
But if you want to limit the character's jumps to a number, instead of using boolean, why not use an int to represent the number of jumps the character has left?

For example:
On jump:

```
if (jumpsLeft >0){
    jumpsLeft -= 1;
    jump();
}
```

On hitting ground again:

```
jumpsLeft = 2;
```

Comment: Hi @user55564 Thanks for the reply. I found the solution to my issue please see my comment above. I have tried your solution before however the issue was that the number of jumps left was being reset when collecting anything within the level, as my reset Jumps Left int was being reset when grounded(IsGround = true).

Answer (score 0):

The code looks sound but the effect you're describing could indicate that the item collection is on the same layer as the ground - thus calling that same code and resetting `grounded` and `doubleJump` on contact. I'd put them on their own `Collectible` layer.